# Commit-hook: mark "bugs-everywhere" issue mentioned in the message as done

Tags: git, githooks

I use `git` and `bugs-everywhere` in my project. If you don't know the latter, it's a simple text file based issue tracker, i.e. bugs are simply files, and modifying them is done with the command-line tool `be`. The files themselves are stored in the git repository. The idea of `bugs-everywhere` is to keep the issue statuses in sync with the code you commit.

What I'd like to achieve: If a programmer commits changes and references the bug in the message he just fixed / feature he implemented (e.g. the message is something like `fixed #123`), I'd like to mark the issue as done using the corresponding `be` command. This obviously changes the issue file. I then want these changes to be included in the current commit.

Since I need to parse the commit message, I can't use a `pre-commit` hook but need to use a `commit-msg` hook. But I can't find any information whether or not it is possible to change *what is being committed* but only the *message* for the commit.

My idea is, in the `commit-msg` hook, to always reject such commits, but also do another commit which includes the corresponding changes in the issue file. This leaves some open questions:

- Is it possible to do a commit during a commit-msg hook?
- Is it possible to reliably find out which files the user wanted to commit originally? (I guess I can simply use the comment lines in the commit message, but aren't they possibly truncated?)

Or is there a different approach you can think of?

Another idea, not really solving the above problem, is to only use the hook to check if the programmer *already marked the issue as done*. My primary goal is to avoid forgetting to mark the issue as done.

Comment: As a general rule, it's bad form to modify what's about to be committed in a hook, but not so bad to reject the commit.  As for modifying or inspecting the commit, you can look at the index, but with `git commit -a` or `git commit file ...` git uses a different (non-standard) index, so this is a bit perilous.  Probably a better way to get "mark issue done and commit result" is to write a script that does those in that order.  Then a hook that checks to make sure the marking is correct, aborting the commit if not, can remind the user to use the script, rather than a direct `git commit`.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your honest advice. I guess I go for the other direction: a prepare-commit-msg hook inserts "fixed #123" notes if the issue file was changed in that way (detected using git diff). The user sees this immediately in his commit message editor. Then maybe, but I guess it's not necessary, check in the commit-msg hook that issues and message are matching.

Comment: The `prepare-commit-msg` hook runs *before* you get a chance to edit the commit message, so it's fine to fuss with the text there: the user gets to see what's going in.  Changing it in the commit-msg hook, *after* the user has set it, just seems sort of rude.  (I thought, based on your text above, that this is what you were going to do.  Of course, it's *your* repo, so it's really up to you.)  BTW, inspecting the index in the hook itself is safe enough, just remember that `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` may point to an alternative file (if you're inclined to fuss with it).

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, it's not really recommended to configure the workflow like that.

As an alternative, I went for **the other way around**: when a commit includes a change to an issue file, mention the bug in the prepared commit message.

I implemented this mechanism using the `prepare-commit-msg` hook which I'll describe here step by step:

- First, I list all currently fixed bugs according to the files in the current working directory, and get their UUID:

  ```
  fixedbugs="`be list -x --status fixed | sed -n 's#  <uuid>\(.*\)</uuid>#\1#p'`"
  ```
- For each of them, I check the following two things: Has the bug already been fixed in `HEAD`? Is the issue file itself staged for commit (to allow partial commits)? This can be checked with a `git diff` between `HEAD` and `--staged`; then finding out if a line `"status": "fixed"` has been *added* according to the diff using `grep`. (Note that here, the hex string `2111156...` is the ID of my bugdir, replace with your own):

  ```
  for bug in $fixedbugs; do
      if git diff HEAD --staged .be/211156fd-fa49-4e87-878c-7642f7163a4b/bugs/$bug/values | grep '^\+    "status": "fixed",.\?$' > /dev/null; then
          # (do something with $bug, e.g. `be show $bug...`)
      fi
  done
  ```
- For each such issue "to be committed as being fixed now" (within the `if` above), I collect some information and concatenate the text lines to be prepended to the commit message:

  ```
  # collect information
  details="`be show -x 211156fd-fa49-4e87-878c-7642f7163a4b/$bug`"
  short="`echo "$details" | sed -n 's#.*<short-name>\(.*\)</short-name>.*#\1#p'`"
  shorter="`echo "$short" | sed 's#211/##'`"   # remove bugdir
  summary="`echo "$details" | sed -n 's#.*<summary>\(.*\)</summary>.*#\1#p'`"

  # prepend string in format 'fixed #123: "foo bar is broken"'
  prepend="$prepend`echo fixed \#$shorter: \\\"$summary\\\"`\n"
  ```
- At the end of the hook, prepend this string to the prepared commit message:

  ```
  tmpfile="`mktemp`
  echo "$prepend" > $tmpfile
  cat "$1" >> $tmpfile
  mv "$tmpfile" "$1"
  ```

Full hook file is published as a gist at https://gist.github.com/leemes/dd336e5fc88096ad6924

If you have any suggestions for improvement or spot a bug, please comment.